# django dajax css width attribute

Tags: django, dajaxice

I'm trying to modify the width css property of a div using dajax in django.  I've tried every variation I can think of with no success.  I am using dajax successfully for many other things, mostly for "innerHTML" manipulation.

Here is an example of things I've tried...

Here is a simple div that I want to change the width of

```
<div id="mysillydiv" style="width: 1px;">some stuff</div>
```

Here are some dajax functions I've tried...

```
# does not work
dajax.assign('#mysillydiv', 'css.width', '50px')

# nope, this isn't it either
dajax.assign('#mysillydiv', 'style.width', '50px')
```

You get the idea.  I just need to know what the attribute is to access that width property. :)

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to dajax, but according to their [list of API calls](https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajax/wiki), it looks like you'd have two options.

Either use assign to modify the style attribute:

```
dajax.assign('#mysillydiv', 'style', 'width:50px')
```

Or, use CSS classes instead of inline CSS styles:

```
dajax.add_css_class('#mysillydiv', 'largersize')
```

And handle #mysilldiv.largersize in your CSS file...